# RDS vCPU and RAM Configuration Properties

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We can't seem to find a way to retrieve the vCPU and RAM Configuration properties via any AWS/CloudWatch API call in C#. We're able to get the other properties on this screen using API calls but these two are giving us some trouble. Anybody have any idea how to do this?

[AWS RDS Instance configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFPmx.png)

Hopefully the image link I pasted is available. If not, the exact screen is AWS > RDS > Databases > <MY_RDS_INSTANCE_NAME > Configuration Tab

Comment: [describe-orderable-db-instance-options — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-orderable-db-instance-options.html) can provide _some_ of those options, but not all of them.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, we are using the describe method. Our issue is specifically how can we get the vCPU and RAM property values. Those don't seem to be available via the describe method. We get all the other properties fine, just need a way to retrieve vCPU and RAM :D

Comment: I don't think such an API call exists. It is static data that you can store, based on information from the documentation or pricing pages. It took a long time until there was a similar API call for Amazon EC2 ([describe-instance-types — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-types.html)).